gRPC C++ intercept a new connection in server
How can I intercept a new gRPC connection in a gRPC server?
To be clear: I'm not interested in new RPC calls, only about new connections.
I've tried SetAuthMetadataProcessor but unfortunately that works on the RPC level.

Though your custom grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor will be called for every RPC request, you can add custom properties to it which will be there for all the requests of a connection, so you can use it to distinguish between different connections.
